# How to redirect to the same url in 'after_update_path_for' with devise ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I want to redirect to the same page after updating the password.
I have two views:

- `edit.html.haml` (account_path)
- `edit_password.html.haml` (account_change_password_path)

When I update the account(edit or edit_password), it redirects me to root page (I want to re-direct to the same page).

When I try to change the password (with errors) in edit_password view  it shows me the devise errors in "edit view" (it should show me the devise errors in edit_password view).

I tried to solve this with:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 # ...

 protected
 def after_update_path_for(resource)
  redirect_to :back
 end
end
```

but it does not work.

How can I make it redirect to the same url?

Answer (score 1):

You've got it almost right.  So those path helpers for devise, `after_sign_up_path`, `after_sign_in_path`, `after_update_path` are expecting a URL, specifically, just a string.

For others hitting this page: The keys to making after update work are:

1. Create a registrations controller to override the after_update_path method (see the docs on how to do this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers
2. Add the method `after_update_path` in the `protected` section of your custom registration controller
3. Add the path, as a string or stored string as the only outputted element in that method

An example if you want to redirect back to the page you came from:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 # ...
 protected
 def after_update_path_for(resource)
      request.referrer || edit_user_registration_path
 end
end
```

So if the user was on edit_password_path, it takes them back there.  However, if a security conscience user has antivirus or no-follow software that removes referrers from their browser, then your back-up is to take the user to the full registration path.

Comment: thx dude its work, but why the "devise errors" are only shown in "edit.html.haml (account_path) view" ? when i try to update the password with errors(for example the new password and confirmation new password are diferent) it redirect me to "account_path" with the errors in this view.